# Images do not vertically align properly within div in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

Images in the `images` div seem to vertically align and center properly in Chrome, Firefox, and IE, but not in Safari. In Safari, the pictures are pushed below/out of the `images` div and appear below the div, bleeding into the `description` div like so:

**http://postimg.org/image/vsoifbf1x/**

Below is a jsfiddle of the slideshow showing the first image aligned in the center. The JS will not work because of how I have referenced the images in an array, but the slideshow works for me and I am just concerned about the images aligning vertically. They align properly in jsfiddle, Chrome and Firefox, just not in Safari:

**http://jsfiddle.net/bytyrurh/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#images {
    height: 548px;
    width: 898px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

#images img {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
}
```

Here's the code that will probably work for you.

Comment: Problem still remains in Safari after trying this.

Comment: This simplified my code in `#images img` greatly, but did not fix the problem. Adding the following to `#images img` fixed the code:

    `-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);`
    `-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);`

Looks like it was a toolkit problem haha.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about all the vendor prefixes. Those are new CSS3 properties which are still not adopted by all the browsers completely so you have to use prefixes. You can check what properties need vendor prefixes on this website http://caniuse.com/ :)